# Team City with SVN using local checkout

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, teamcity

I am using Team City (Latest Version) for deployment and it works fine when using the http url of the repo. The project is very big and it takes many hours for a checkout. So I wanted to use a local checkout in Team City which is updated regularly. But when I use

> file:///E:/MY_PROJ_SVN

as svn url I get an error

```
Unable to open ra_local_session
```

Most probably because I don't have a local svn server installed, which I don't want to.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by local check out? Where are you specifying the file location file:///E:/MY_PROJ_SVN? In VCS Settings?

Comment: @Nadeem In SVN connection settings

Comment: @Nadeem by local checkout I mean a checkout of repo on my disk

Comment: Your disk mean disk on the teamcity agent machine. Have you tried creating a VCS.

Comment: @Nadeem The error is displayed in VCS after I replaced http url with local file url

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which OS you are running on  but the error basically means you are missing the required svn library for using the file protocol.

The way SVN works is it requires different libraries for using different protocal(http,svn,file). If you want to use file protocol you would need a library compatible with your OS.

I would probably need some more info like :
1. whats the SVN version you are using on teamcity
2. What OS are you running on
3. What SVN client/libraries do you have installed on the teamcity host (I believe you have created your svn file on the same host where teamcityruns. Correct me if I am wrong)